# PHP seems only to recognize my index.php and nothing else

Tags: php, html, heroku

So I have the following project structure for a web application (see image below):

[image: File structure]

However, when I run in localhost or deploy to Heroku for that matter, it seems that the only php file that is ever being read is my `index.php` if I try to login, I am met with a status of 404 - not found for my `login.php` file though I clearly have it there, the same goes for such pages as my `homepage.php` etc. Any ideas the cause of this?

Within the php files, I have lines to redirect to other php files using the `header` function. Such as:

```php
header("Location: homepage.php");
```

Comment: What does your web server configuration look like? And consider adding the contents of `index.php` to your post.

Comment: your file is `hompage.php`, not `homepage.php`
So to check if it's the redirect wrong, open devtools, enable "preserve logs" in network tab and try open the file.